# What abbreviations in OOM Killer memory statistics report means?

Tags: oom, oom-killer

When OOM Killer or kernel reports memory state it uses the next abbreviations

```
Node 0 DMA: 26*4kB (M) 53*8kB (UM) 33*16kB (ME) 23*32kB (UME) 6*64kB (ME) 7*128kB (UME) 1*256kB (M) 2*512kB (ME) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 4352kB
Node 0 DMA32: 803*4kB (UME) 3701*8kB (UMEH) 830*16kB (UMH) 2*32kB (H) 0*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB (H) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 46420kB
```

I understand some of them, for example `M` - movable `UMH` - unmovable high. But I can not find what means `E` 
Where I can find documentation about it?

For example I have the next message,

```
page allocation stalls for 27840ms, order:0, mode:0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE)
```

what means process requests 4kb page `(2^0 * 4kb)`, that should be coded as (MH) Am I right? Or `HIGHUSER` is coded in different way?

Comment: I received the answer on Unix & Linux StackExchange site https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/517077/351247